# Server Boost Tracker Bot Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Help me to send a message when someone `Boost The Server`, here some code for example.
Please help me, guys :)

```
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(oldMember.roles.size < newmember.roles.size) {
        const fetchedLogs = await oldMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE',
    });

        const roleAddLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
        if (!roleAddLog ) return;
        const { executor, target, extra } = kickLog;
        console.log(`Role ${extra.name} added to ${<@target.id>} by ${<@executor.id>}`)
    }
});
```

Comment: `Please help me` isn't a question. You need additional details. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `Nitro Booster` role gets assigned to a member:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const hadRole = oldMember.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster');
  const hasRole = newMember.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster');

  if (!hadRole && hasRole) {
    newMember.guild.channels.get(/* channel ID */).send('Someone boosted the server');
  }

  // if you want to check which members are boosted, you can check how many have the `Nitro Booster` role:
  const boostedUsers = newMember.guild.members.array().filter(member => member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster'));

  console.log(boostedUsers.length); // how many members are boosted
});
```

Comment: is this already tested?
and i have one question again, can you tracking boost status? like how many boost now in the server.

Comment: @totototDEV I have added code to get all boosted users.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/odA5SRx 

no, i mean total boost server and some error undefined, u can see the sample on that url

Comment: @totototDEV I'm not sure what you mean by *how many boost now in the server*.

Comment: ah ok, btw i got some error 
`(node:3177) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).array is not a function`

im using discord js v11 now, what about undefined username?

Comment: @totototDEV Did you add the `async` keyword on the first line of the code?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6fLvXds ya like this

Comment: @totototDEV Yes, like that.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4jyKhcW still get error

Comment: i using discord.js v11

Comment: I got rid of `cache`. It should work now.

Comment: btw, i cant get the Tag the newMember 
example:
Miez#8781

Comment: @totototDEV Did you try `newMember.user.tag`?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [GuildMember#premiumSince](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=premiumSince) for an approach that does not rely on roles:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if (oldMember.premiumSince !== newMember.premiumSince) {
    //your code here
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the better way 